# Firebase Magic Link not complete in Android App

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a React Native Project using Expo Managed Workflow.
The App is built as a expo-dev-client.
I use Firebase Native SDK to authenticate via `sendSignInLinkToEmail()`

I managed to request the magic link for login. It arrives and when I click it on my android device, the App comes to focus and I am even able to listen to the dynamic link when it comes in.
Problem is it does not validate with `isSignInWithEmailLink()` because the link I get is only the `continueURL` parameter of the original link in the Email.

I really don't know where the link is being cut off but I need the complete link from the Email to use `signInWithEmailLink()` which obviously doesn't work.
When I manually insert the link from the email into `signInWithEmailLink()` everything works as expected.

I really hope someone has experienced this issue and can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

My Bad. Apparently I was using a Dynamic Link from firebase as I did not have action codes set correct as in:

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};
```